# Architectural Land Sub division

Tags: add-on

Related to Architectural

I have a land i want to sub-divde into several plot systems. How to make Plots in that Land and Division of Land into Plots for example 30x30, 60x40 and road, garden, Space Civic Amenities, etc. Reference Video link given below. Is there any addon can sub divide with proportional way adjusting the parameters.

[Reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4czWq0X4x0)

Comment: using arrays will help

Answer (score 1):

In case of creating geometry parametricaly, you can use addons:

[Sverchok](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Nodes/Sverchok) ([github](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok)) -  is a powerful parametric tool for architects, allowing geometry to be programmed visually with nodes.

[Animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) - this tool mostly for animation, but maybe it can be also useful for you

Anyway, you must create your own logic using this addons (or find node trees in internet), so you must study how to create meshes using logic nodes from this addons.

Comment: If an addon exist will be much use for all. Just with the options fill up they can have a good layout. If the addon creator are listening maybe useful for all architect users. Not jumping to paid software. Thanks for the link and addon i never seen that addon lets try.